# What is the fastest ever closed question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748502/i-need-some-help-asap) was opened, closed 60 seconds later, then deleted 113 seconds after that.

[image]

That must be some kind of record! Does SO keep statistics on questions that have been closed in super fast times by human users? What is the fastest?

Comment: You probably need to rule out spam which is often removed in just a very few seconds.

Comment: @greg-449 yeah, i guess closed by human users is an important addition.

Comment: Actually the spam is closed by humans with the help of SmokeDetector

Comment: Last week we had a question closed in like 50 seconds. It was a question that was obviously bad from just the title, and there was a ton of "mod users" online.

Comment: The work of [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45385628#45385628) :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fastest closed question is [this one (>10K+)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193854/7296893), asked in 2008. It got closed within 5 seconds by the author, and then deleted, since it's obviously a test question.

The fastest closed non-deleted question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44887326/7296893), which got marked as a duplicate 8 seconds after it had been asked.

You can easily query this information from SEDE by subtracting the closed date from the open date (see [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/987628/fastest-closed-question))

The fastest closed non-deleted question that got closed by 5 users I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20384167/7296893), closed in 55 seconds. You can use [this substantially more complex query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/987641/fastest-closed-question-with-5-voters) to look for questions with 5 closers, but note it only works with non-deleted questions.

Comment: oh my god 8sec! .. I thought I was fast closing in less than 30s :/ (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53564952/8620333)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, And it's not an accident this user closed many question under 10 sec.